# AC functions on a bounded, non-compact interval

Tags: real-analysis

I’m looking for examples of absolutely continuous functions on a bounded, open or half-open interval that satisfy at least one of the two conditions below. To clarify, I don’t mean the functions only to be absolutely continuous on the compact subintervals of $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$.

I’m uncertain about the existence of such examples. If it is impossible to provide them, I’d like to know why. The two conditions are the following:

1. $f’ \notin L^{1}([a,b])$
2. $f$ is essentially not absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$. By this I mean that it is impossible to extend $f$ on all of $[a,b]$ in such a way that $f \in AC([a,b])$. I think that this should only happen when $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}{f(x)}$ or $\lim_{x \rightarrow b^-}{f(x)}$ do not exist.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you define $AC$ on a non-compact interval?

Comment: Just like Wikipedia does: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: Actually, I now noticed that Wikipedia takes the collection of pairwise disjoint subintervals in the definition to be finite. In the definition I have I let it be countable, but the two are equivalent.

Comment: I think that the function $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x}), x\in (0,1]$ satisfies your second condition. The limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $0^+$ does not exist

Comment: My answer in the above comment was wrong because the function I gave is continuous, but not absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, (2) is obviously impossible: If $f$ is AC on $(a,b)$ then it is uniformly continuous, hence extends continuously to $[a,b]$.

And this shows that (1) is impossible: Suppose $a<x_1<y_1<\dots<x_n<y_n<b$ and $\sum(y_j-x_j)<\delta$ imply $\sum|f(y_j)-f(x_j)|<\epsilon$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it follows that $a\le x_1<y_1<\dots<x_n<y_n\le b$ and $\sum(y_j-x_j)<\delta$ imply $\sum|f(y_j)-f(x_j)|\le\epsilon$.